# Deleting a directory, recreating it, and adding files to it

Tags: c#, windows, file-io, explorer

My issue is this. I was creating a directory and filing it with files for running a specific process and on subsequent runs it would delete the directory, recreate it and start filling it with files.

> root\scripts\'Many files'

All this code seemed to run fine without errors until I opened up my Windows Explorer window and navigated into the 'scripts' directory.  When I would run it again it would kick me out of the folder as expected when it deleted, but it would throw an exception trying to add files to the directory, and when I looked the 'scripts' directory didn't even exits.

```
DirectoryNotFoundException was caught: Could not find a part of the path
```

My Code looked like this.

```
if (Directory.Exists(scriptsDirectory))
    Directory.Delete(scriptsDirectory, true);
Directory.Create(scriptsDirectory));
File.WriteAllText(scriptsDirectory + fileName, output);
```

I looked on the internet and found this: [Windows Explorer and Directory.Delete()](http://www.markbetz.net/2010/05/23/windows-explorer-and-directory-delete/)

It seems there's something odd with Windows Explorer, but my issue was different. It wouldn't throw an exception on delete, but when I was trying to add files to the directory, b/c the createDirectory didn't seem to fire while I was in the directory.

My solution is below.

Comment: To any moderators: I wanted to post these here for any looking for it, I wasn't sure if I should keep my answer in the initial post or if I should answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was instead of Deleting the Directory, I instead deleted all the files from the directory, and that worked for me.

```
if (Directory.Exists(strScriptsDirectory))
{                
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strScriptsDirectory);

    // Delete the files
    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        fileInfo.Delete();
    // Delete the directories here if you need to.
}
else
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strScriptsDirectory);
```

This fix might not work well for all solutions and the solution provided in the link doesn't seem too great. 
Another solution we tired was too write a while (true) loop that had a try catch to try to create the directory and add a file to it (if the add file caused an exception it would be caught and try again) and if it succeeded it would delete the test file and break out of the while.

Does anyone have any cleaner solutions that would allow you to delete a directory and recreate without having to worry about if a user is within an Explorer window?

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question.

Comment: @dustmouse I just wasn't sure considering I answered it before posting, but I did want to make a post about it b/c it seemed so odd to me and coworkers.